# How to trigger Gitlab CI only if CURRENT commit contains changes to some file?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I a have a Gitlab stage that I only want to run if there are changes to some file. I have tried using `only` and `if: changes...` however those not work as I want.

I want that this stage is only triggered if the current commit (no matter if it is a merge request or pushed to main) contains changes to some file

My stage:

```
cache frontend:
  stage: cache
  cache: &frontend_cache
    key: frontend-packages
    paths:
      - frontend/node_modules/
      - frontend/.yarn/
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - yarn install --immutable
  only:
    changes:
      - frontend/yarn.lock
```

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) this seems to be correct.

Comment: Using `rules` might be an alternative option.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Comment: @Bouke it does not work with `only`

Comment: @Bouke with `rules` it is triggered if there is any commit in the branch than contains changes to yarn.lock. If a make a new commit without changes to yarn.lock it will still trigger the pipeline

Comment: You might try with another file, just to rule out it's not related to yarn.lock but to the pipeline definition itself.

Comment: I've tried and it still doesn't work. I don't know why Gitlab uses  difference of all commits from a branch respect to another instead of current commit to previous ones

Comment: Whith current commit, you mean the last one ? Even if you push several commits you want to make a rule only on changes on a specific file only if these changes append in the last commit ?

Comment: @fmdaboville Yes, that is what I want